# google calendar recurring event exclusion: what does it mean for next recurrence?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using the google calendar API to build a calendar app. I don't know if Google Calendar already works the way I want it to or if I have to write a workaround.

If I have a google calendar event happening every other day and exclude 1 day, does the calendar still count that day when it alternates?

For example, if I exclude an occurrence on Monday, does the calendar still count that day as having that event, so that the next occurrence would be on  Wednesday, or would the calendar consider it like the day never happened, and reorder itself so that now the event happens on Tuesday, and the next is on Thursday, then Saturday, etc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official Calendar API for reference on [recurring events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurring_events):

> **Recurring events** Some events occur multiple times on a regular schedule, such as weekly meetings, birthdays, and holidays. Other than
>   having different start and end times, these repeated events are often
>   identical.
>
> Events are called recurring if they repeat according to a defined
>   schedule. Single events are non-recurring and happen only once.
>
> Recurrence rule The schedule for a recurring event is defined in two
>   parts:
>
> Its start and end fields (which define the first occurrence, as if
>   this were just a stand-alone single event), and
>
> Its recurrence field (which defines how the event should be repeated
>   over time).
>
> The recurrence field contains an array of strings representing one or
>   several RRULE, RDATE or EXDATE properties as defined in RFC 5545.
>
> The RRULE property is the most important as it defines a regular rule
>   for repeating the event. It is composed of several components. Some of
>   them are:
>
> FREQ — The frequency with which the event should be repeated (such as
>   "DAILY" or "WEEKLY"). Required.
>
> INTERVAL — Works together with FREQ to specify how often the event
>   should be repeated. For example, "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2" means once
>   every two days.
>
> COUNT — Number of times this event should be repeated.
>
> You can use either COUNT or UNTIL to specify the end of the event
>   recurrence. Don't use both in the same rule. UNTIL — The date or
>   date-time until which the event should be repeated (inclusive).
>
> BYDAY — Days of the week on which the event should be repeated ("SU",
>   "MO", "TU", etc.). Other similar components include BYMONTH,
>   BYYEARDAY, and BYHOUR.